# New Relic Warning - There are both old and new time metrics for this time window.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, newrelic

In our new relic dashboard, we are getting this warning - "There are both old and new time metrics for this time window. The response time is accurate, but if you use asynchronous code the stacked bars may not be. To fix this, upgrade all of your agents to versions that support the new time metrics". Does this mean the response time is inaccurate and do we need to update the agent?

Answer (score 0):

The warning message that you shared seems to indicate that the *response time* will be accurate, but that the stacked bars indicating the *total time spent* may not be.  Some more helpful information may be found here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/data-analysis/user-interface-functions/view-your-data/response-time

I suspect from the warning message that your application runs on multiple servers with different versions of the New Relic .NET agent, some with (newer) async support than others.  You may be able to determine that on the New Relic "Environment" page, or if you are using New Relic "Servers", by navigating to each host there to determine the New Relic Agent version.  This page may be helpful: [Async support in .NET](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/additional-installation/async-support-net)

The best practice would be to run the same version of the .NET agent on all of your hosts, and I expect that doing this will clear that warning.